# How can add new row without insert with ado.net

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, ado.net

```
  stokService = new StokService();
  var stok = stokService.stokList("Select * from xstSabit where stokKodu= '" + txtStokKodu.Text + "' ");
  dgvSepet.DataSource = stok;
```

this **stok** selected and viewed in Datagridview there is no problem. I want to add one more **stok** to Datagridview with existing **stok** but in this code it is only return one **stok**. How can ı add new rows without insert ?

Comment: "adding" without "insert" makes no sense. That's the same thing.
Do you want to create without insert ?

Comment: If your `StockService` allows that, you have bigger problems than this question. Check [this ilustration](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: The DGV has an option to Allow Editing which add a blank row into the DGV without adding row to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is impossible. The alternative would be to upgrade an existing row if inserting new raw is not so mandatory.